# How to set Angular Material primary color to custom value?

Tags: angular-material

I need to set custom color as primary in Angular Material. Reading some theaming guides and SO answers like [Changing Primary Color in Angular Material 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734518/changing-primary-color-in-angular-material-2) shows that I need to pick color from predefined set of colors. Can I use custom value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use any color you want, but it must be defined in your own custom 'palette' in order to be used in theming. Have a look at the [Angular Material palettes](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/6.2.x/src/lib/core/theming/_palette.scss) for examples. You would then use your palette in place of the material palettes like `$mat-blue` when you create your theme:

```
$my-blue: (
  50: #e3f2fd,
  ...
)
...
$primary: mat-palette($my-blue);
...
$theme: mat-light-theme($primary, $accent);
```

Search the web for `angular material palette tool` or similar. There are a number of free online tools for creating palettes from a base color.

Comment: How do I know how to map colors? Eg should i use 50,100 or 200 ?

Comment: You need to do some research if you don't know that. You should define all of them: 50-900, plus the 'A's, and the contrasts. As I said - find an online tool to make life easier, or simply copy one the the Angular Material ones and change the values to your color. Keep in mind that a palette represents varying shades of a single color, plus contrasts colors used to display text over the corresponding palette color (so contrasts are typically white, black, or grey and not colored).

Comment: Thats the thing, I would like to skip whole palette creation but it looks like I cannot. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Yes - that's right - you need your own palette unless the color you want is already in one of the Angular Material palettes.

Comment: @G.Tranter Thanks, voted up. I think it is enough just generate scss file and use it in our project, is that true?