# Change initial color of an Angular 9 mat-input

Tags: css, angular, colors, mat-input

I have a standard matInput field inside a standard mat-form-field, which is in a standard [formGroup] div. The background of the parent area is dark and the default color of the input is dark. That doesn't work well. Here's a sample of the HTML..

```
<div [formGroup]="myInfo">
  Year: &nbsp;
  <mat-form-field>
    <input class="myClass" style="color: white" matInput (keypress)="numericOnly($event)" placeholder='YYYY' 
           formControlName="yearControl">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Looking online and based on answers here, I see how to change things in the .scss like:

```
.childClass {
  input { color: #fff !important; }
  label.mat-input-placeholder { color: #fff !important; }
  ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-label { color: #fff !important; }
  ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-ripple { color: #fff !important; }
  ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline { color: #fff !important; }
}
```

This finally changed the placeholder text and entered text to be white, but the underline is still black. Thanks for your ongoing suggestions.

Comment: https://medium.com/wineofbits/how-to-change-angular-material-theme-in-just-5-minutes-d8719d1f026 check this link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734518/changing-primary-color-in-angular-material-2

Answer (score 0):

It's doesn't work becouse yours selector

```
::ng-deep .mat-focused .mat-form-field-label
```

contains

```
.mat-focused
```

And it works only when you focused on field

Just change the selector

`::ng-deep .mat-form-field-label` and placeholder color

```
label.mat-input-placeholder
```

Comment: change it to what?

Comment: edit my answer, you need to change placeholder and not foused label

Comment: I have added this to my .scss and it does not work... 
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-label label.mat-input-placeholder {
    color: white;
}
the input field is still showing black text.

Comment: could you show code snipet , where you want change text color

Comment: edited original post to show HTML... but the description was already accurate.

Answer (score 0):

i changed input color to a brighter color with a dark background like this:

i build my own input component switched-input.component

html:

```
 // switched-input.component.html
 <mat-form-field>
   <input matInput placeholder="{{placeholder}}" [formControl]="inputControl"/>
 </mat-form-field>
```

scss:

```
// switched-input.component.scss
mat-form-field {
  width: 100%;
}
// color of the text typed by the user when input is selected
input {
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

ts:

```
// switched-input.component.ts
import { FormHelper } from './../../../helper/form.helper';
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'switched-input',
  templateUrl: './switched-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./switched-input.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class SwitchedInputComponent implements OnInit {
  inputControl: FormControl;

  @Input() placeholder: string;

  @Input() set control(controlObj: FormControl) {
    this.inputControl = controlObj;
    if (this.placeholder && this.placeholder !== '') {
      this.placeholder = this.translateService.instant(this.placeholder);
    }
  }

  get control(): FormControl {
    return this.inputControl;
  }

  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {}

  ngOnInit() {

  }    
}
```

additionally to change the underline color aswell as the label color of the input fields i had to use the following styles in my apps main styles.scss file

```
// styles.scss
// underline color of mat input fields
.mat-form-field-underline {
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
// label color of mat input fields
.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy .mat-form-field-label {
  color: #fff;
}
```

[image: bright font, dark background]

Comment: Basically, I think you are saying to add input { color: #fff !important; } to my .scss. I tried this and it did not work. Was there more to your solution? Perhaps you have something in styles.scss that is doing the trick?

Comment: Updated my original question with your first suggestion. Still need the underline to be white.

Comment: ye you are right i have some styles in my styles.scss for the underline  thank you for pointing that out i will edit my answer. i tried out putting the style i found in my styles.scss into the component but it didnt work.

Comment: /nod. I can't make a change at the styles.scss level, and I already have ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline { color: #fff !important; } at the module childClass level, but it doesn't seem to be working. Thanks for the ongoing attempts.

Comment: have you tried working with viewEncapsulate.none in your child component?
np bud